# How do I add Object#tap method to my Ruby 1.8.5 core?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have Ruby version 1.8.5 installed and I am unable to update to a newer one since those are not available for the Linux distribution I am using.

Unfortunately, some gems I have installed use the `Object#tap` method internally which I believe was not available until the 1.8.7 ruby core version.

Naturally, whenever I try to use these ruby gems I face this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `tap'  (...)

Is there an easy way to add it to my ruby (1.8.5) core so I can seamlessly use these gems?

Comment: You should use RVM and get the latest Ruby...

Comment: My deepest condolences to you for actually having to use this. But seriously, you should really try to upgrade to avoid *a world of pain* with about any ruby-software not provided by your core distribution.

Comment: There is no Ruby update available to the Linux distro I am using. I have found an easy workaround which is to install the [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) gem, in case anyone is interested!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tap used to be part of ActiveSupport between [Rails 2.3.2 to 2.3.8](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/tap). The source is [still available on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/misc.rb#L56) of course, but it is a simple method to monkey patch in.

```
class Object
  def tap
    yield self
    self
  end unless Object.respond_to?(:tap)
end
```

Edit: As pointed out by the original poster the [andand gem](https://github.com/raganwald/andand) also has an implementation of `Object#tap` available.

Comment: Thank you for your help! In the meantime I have found other solution which is installing the [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) gem since, as the author says, _This library implements Object#tap for Ruby 1.8 and enhances it_. Please consider adding this alternate option to your answer before I mark it as correct ;)